# Queue Worker Thread stops working, thread safety issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

i want to introduce my problem first.

I have several WorkingThreads that are receiving a string, processing the string and afterwards sending the processed string to a global Queue like this:

```
class Main {
  public static Queue<String> Q;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //start working threads
  }
}
```

WorkingThread.java:

```
class WorkingThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    String input;
    //do something with input
    Main.q.append(processedString);
}
```

So now every 800ms another Thread called Inserter dequeues all the entries to formulate some sql, but thats not important.

```
class Inserter extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    while(!Main.Q.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.print(".");
      // dequeue and formulate some SQL
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works for about 5 to 10 minutes but then suddenly, i cannot see any dots printed (what is basically a heartbeat for the Inserter). The Queue is not empty i can assure that but the inserter just wont work even though it get started regulary.

I have a suspision that there is a problem when a worker wants to insert something while the Inserter dequeues the Queue, could this possibly be some kind of "deadlock"?

I really hope somebody has an explanation for this behaviour. I am looking forward to learn ;).

EDIT: I am using

```
Queue<String> Q = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: Most importantly, what `Queue` implementation are you using?

Comment: i edited that information: LinkedList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a `synchronized` or thread safe `Queue` therefore you have a race hazard. Your use of a `LinkedList` shows a (slightly scary) lack of knowledge of this fact. You may want to read more about threading and thread safety before you try and tackle any more threaded code.

You **must** either synchronize manually or use one of the existing implementations provided by the JDK. Producer/consumer patterns are usually implemented using one of the `BlockingQueue` implementations.

A `BlockingQueue` of a bounded size will block producers trying to `put` if the queue is full. A `BlockingQueue` will always block consumers if the queue is empty.

This allows you to remove all of your custom logic that spins on the queue and waits for items.

A simple example using Java 8 lambdas would look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BlockingQueue<String> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    final Runnable consumer = () -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(q.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    executorService.submit(consumer);
    final Stream<Runnable> producers = IntStream.range(0, 5).mapToObj(i -> () -> {
        final Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        while (true) {
            q.add("Consumer " + i + " putting " + random.nextDouble());
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    });
    producers.forEach(executorService::submit);
}
```

The `consumer` blocks on the `BlockingQueue.take` method and immediately there is an item available, it will be woken and will print the item. If there are no items, the thread will be suspended - allowing the physical CPU to do something else.

The `producers` each push a `String` onto the queue using `add`. As the queue is unbounded, `add` will always return true. In the case where there is likely to be a backlog of work the for `consumer` you can bound the queue and use the `put` method (that throws an `InterruptedException` so requires a `try..catch` which is why it's easier to use `add`) - this will automatically create flow control.

Comment: Can i just use the BlockingQueue Interface without using labmdas and java 1.8

Comment: Yes, of course. The lambads have nothing to do with the `BlockingQueue` - they implement `Runnable`...

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to synchronize access to your Queue or
use ConcurrentLinkedQueue see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

or as also suggested using a BlockingQueue (depending on your requirements) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

For a more detailed explanation of the BlockingQueue see

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html

Comment: A `BlockingQueue` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Seems more like *synchronization* issue.. You are trying to do a simulation of - `Producer - Consumer problem`. You need to synchronize your Queue or use a `BlockingQueue`. You probably have a race condition.